# Spark: how to generate several elements in map (python)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have data that consists of key and list of values.
    rdd = (Key, [Value])

and what I want is that:

```
rdd.map(lambda pair: func(pair))
```

where function return several (Value, New_value) for each pair. Note, that New_value also depend on Key!

So, simply, after using `.map()` on

```
(key1, [Value1, Value2])
(key2, [Value3, Value4, Value5])
```

I want to receive:

```
(Value1, NewValue1)
(Value2, NewValue2)
(Value3, NewValue3)
(Value4, NewValue4)
(Value5, NewValue5)
```

How can I make it in PySpark?

Comment: Use a list comprehension instead, like `[func(pair) for pair in rdd]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let func, be the concatenated key-value.

```
def func(kv):
    return '-'.join(kv)
```

You want to flatten all the lists to (key, value) pairs

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda kv: ((kv[0], v) for v in kv[1]))
```

Then map `func` across all pairs while keeping the initial value as part of the result

```
 map(lambda kv: (kv[1], func(kv)))
```

In sum,

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda kv: ((kv[0], v) for v in kv[1])).map(lambda kv: (kv[1], func(kv)))
```

Example

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([('k1', ['v1', 'v2']), ('k2', ['v3','v4','v5'])])
>>> rdd.flatMap(lambda kv: ((kv[0], v) for v in kv[1])).map(lambda kv: (kv[1], func(kv))).collect()
[('v1', 'k1-v1'),
 ('v2', 'k1-v2'),
 ('v3', 'k2-v3'),
 ('v4', 'k2-v4'),
 ('v5', 'k2-v5')]
```

Comment: I am sorry. Forgot to mention, that NewValues also depend on Key. Added this information in question.

Comment: Thank you. However I found another solution, you could check it :)

Comment: You just move the generator into the function. Seems fine to me. Mine is more explicit in the steps to expand the nested lists.

Answer (score 0):

I find different to @cricket_007 solution using `yield`

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([('k1', ['v1', 'v2']), ('k2', ['v3','v4','v5'])])
>>> def func(kv):
...     for v in kv[1]:
...         yield (v, kv[0] + '-' + v)
>>>rdd.flatMap(lambda kv: func(kv)).collect()
[('v1', 'k1-v1'), 
 ('v2', 'k1-v2'), 
 ('v3', 'k2-v3'), 
 ('v4', 'k2-v4'), 
 ('v5', 'k2-v5')]
```

Comment: That is not what the code outputs. It outputs `['k1-v1', 'k1-v2', 'k2-v3', 'k2-v4', 'k2-v5']`

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, should be `yield (v, kv[0] + '-' + v)`